# Animating Height and Pushing Divs Below

Tags: html, css

This is what I try to do:

When the user clicks on an image (see screenshot below), I'd like some text associated with this image to show up under the row of images (circles). I have been trying to use a transition for this. My initial test was to create a div (in green) with the position set to relative, and a child div (in red) whose position was set to absolute. I then animated the top property of the child div. This worked okay.

```
.parent { position: relative; }
.child { position: absolute; top: -100; transition: top 1s linear; }
.child:target { top: 0; }
```

The problem is that i have more divs under this text, and I'd like them to be pushed when the text is sliding down (the 'test' text in my example). However this doesn't work, because the parent div's height (in green), as you know,  is not expanded when the children div's position is set to absolute.

My question thus is: is there a way of doing this at all?

Thanks for your ideas.

PS: in the screenshot below, the height of the green box is larger than the height of the red box, because there's actually another red div under the first one, but its opacity is set to 0.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have re-read your question thrice and I am still unable to figure out what you wish to do... :S As far as I understand it there is no need for any absolute positioning, but I probably must be mistaken. A top value of -100 without units doesn't even mean anything as far as I know...

Comment: Yes probably not very well explained. I will try to rephrase it. Why would a negative value for the top property not possible when you use absolute position. Isn't it the top position of the element relative to its parent?

Comment: Because it needs a unit like `px`, `em` or even `%`. Without it it's [ignored](http://jsfiddle.net/E9Lan/) in most if not all browsers.

Comment: by default, it takes px, at least in good browsers ;-)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I realise the original question wasn't easy to understand. So basically, when someone clicks on the image (I changed that with a mouseover) some text shows up underneath. Thus you have one block of text (red box) associated with each image. Now, by default I want all the boxes to be hidden, but when the user moves his/her mouse over one image, I want the text associated with this image to appear (using an animation). And when the text shows up, I want the divs which are below it, to be pushed down.

As suggested in the EXCELLENT answer from Vishwanath, the text blocks need somehow to be contained within a another block. I have changed my requirements a bit, but that was only for aesthetical reasons. When the mouse is over one image, it triggers a JS which computes the heigh of the text block that needs to be displayed (this text block is retrieved through its id). Then we adjust the height of the parent div box using this number. Animation of parent's box is done using CSS3 transition. On onmouseleave, the height of the parent's box is reset to 0, and the text is moved back to an area on the screen, where it's not visible.

Here is my solution:

```
.bio_container
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 2 solid green;
    width: 100%;
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bio
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -200;
    transition: top 1s ease-in-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    border: 1 none green;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1 solid red;
}

</style>
<script>
function setimage()
{
    var all = document.getElementsByClassName("portrait");
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; ++i) {
        var ids = all[i].id;
        all[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + ids + "')";
    }
}
function appear(element)
{
    // compute height of this element
    var tmp = document.getElementById(element);
    var clientHeight = tmp.clientHeight;
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('bio_container');
    container[0].style.height = clientHeight;
    tmp.style.top = 0;
    tmp.style.opacity = 1;
}
function disappear(element)
{
    // compute height of this element
    var tmp = document.getElementById(element);
    var clientHeight = tmp.clientHeight;
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('bio_container');
    container[0].style.height = 0;
    tmp.style.top = -clientHeight;
    tmp.style.opacity = 0;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setimage();">
<div id="wrapper1">
<div style="border: 1 none red; margin: 0;">
<!-- first state to put some text to explain who we are -->
<h2>XXX:</h2>
<div class="newspaper">
<p>In entirely be to at settling felicity. Fruit two match men you seven share.
Needed as or is enough points. Miles at smart no marry whole linen mr.
Income joy nor can wisdom summer. Extremely depending he gentleman improving
intention rapturous as.</p>
</div>
<!-- then add profile / readers can find more information -->
<h2>YYY:</h2>
<a href="#elle1" onmouseover="appear('elle1');" onmouseleave="disappear('elle1');"><div id="images/elle.png" class="portrait"></div></a>
<a href="#elle2" onmouseover="appear('elle2');" onmouseleave="disappear('elle2');"><div id="images/elle2.png" class="portrait"></div></a>
</div>
<div class="bio_container">
<div id="elle1" class="bio">
<p>On no twenty spring of in esteem spirit likely estate. Continue new you
declared differed learning bringing honoured. At mean mind so upon they rent
am walk. Shortly am waiting inhabit smiling he chiefly of in. Lain tore time
gone him his dear sure. Fat decisively estimating affronting assistance not.
Resolve pursuit regular so calling me. West he plan girl been my then up no.
On no twenty spring of in esteem spirit likely estate. Continue new you
declared differed learning bringing honoured. At mean mind so upon they rent
am walk. Shortly am waiting inhabit smiling he chiefly of in. Lain tore time
gone him his dear sure. Fat decisively estimating affronting assistance not.
Resolve pursuit regular so calling me. West he plan girl been my then up no.</p>
</div>
<div id="elle2" class="bio">
<p>asdasd asd asd asd asdas dasd asdasd asdasd asd sdas dasd asd asdasd asd
asd asd asd asd as das dasdasdalksjd lsajd iUoeuwr sdlkjf;sdfj a;sdkjf ad.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div>test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

There can be multiple ways of doing this.

One way I had done this using CSS3 was using height than using absolute positioning. Since height flows normally not having any positioning problems. But the problem with heights is that you need to give fixed height for CSS transition to work. So workaround for that is to have a extra wrapper around the div to expand and use its height and give it to expanding div like below. *Ignore the row and columns classes.*

HTML

```
<div class="small-12 columns  level-1">
    <div class="row category-name ">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <span class="">Click to expand or collapse</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="level-2 level-2-container" style="height: 60px;">
        <div class="grow-wrapper small-12 columns">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.level-2-container {
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
    transition: height 0.5s;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* outline: 1px solid red; */
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click', '.level-1', function(event) {
    var $level1 = $(event.currentTarget);
    var $level2 = $level1.find('.level-2-container');
    var $growWrapper = $level1.find('.grow-wrapper');
    var heightToSet = $growWrapper.height();

    growDiv = $level2[0];
    if (growDiv.clientHeight) {
        $level2.height(growDiv.clientHeight);
        $level2.height(0);
    } else {
        growDiv.style.height = heightToSet + "px";
    }

    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

JS-Fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/hps8p/

Comment: Thank you for this EXCELLENT answer. Excellent in all points, for providing the code and a link to a Fiddle. Now I won't make it as an answer, because your solution is VERY close to my needs but treats a slightly different case, in which the blocks you need to expand/contract are following each other. What I need, is to display one of the red boxes while making the others invisible. See my solution below.

Comment: *eye roll*
"If I call it EXCELLENT in all caps twice, then it's ok to plagarize and not give him the points"
It was exactly what I was looking for, @Vishwanath. Nice answer all around.

Comment: Wow. I remember doing this for a interview assignment. Not using any plugins. Glad that this helped. The raw solution. I believe most of the plugins might be doing similar things. But knowing actual solution is fun...