# CSS Animation to hide and show content like an accordion

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to make content that is visually hidden slide open when a link is clicked.

I have a keyframe animation that I am using to try and set the height from 0px to 100%.  The first click removes the `.sr-only` class and adds the `.open` class which should run the keyframe animation.  I am not sure why the keyframe animation is not working.

Here is a fiddle to my code so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/JkaAL/

Here is the code:  Please note I am just using the -webkit- prefix and testing in just chrome.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="js-link">Click Here</a>

<div class="js-content sr-only">
    <p>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    border: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes openIt {
    0% { height: 1px; }
    100% { height: 100%; }
}

.open {
    position: static;
    width: auto;
    padding: initial;
    margin: initial;
    overflow: visible;
    clip: auto;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-animation: openIt 2s linear;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var $link = $('.js-link'),
    $content = $('.js-content');

$link.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( $content.hasClass('sr-only') ) {
        $content.removeClass('sr-only').addClass('open');
    }
    else if ( $content.hasClass('open') ) {
        $content.removeClass('open').addClass('sr-only');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem why your code is not working is because height animation works only with fixed values in numbers, not with auto or percent height. You can achieve this using a wrapper around your sliding div. I have answered a similar question elsewhere.

[Animating Height and Pushing Divs Below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000070/animating-height-and-pushing-divs-below/25001779#25001779)

HTML

```
<div class="small-12 columns  level-1">
                <div class="row category-name "><div class="small-12 columns"><span class="">Click to expand or collapse</span></div></div>

<div class="level-2 level-2-container" style="height: 60px;">
                    <div class="grow-wrapper small-12 columns">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.level-2-container {
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
    transition: height 0.5s;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* outline: 1px solid red; */
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click', '.level-1', function(event) {
    var $level1 = $(event.currentTarget);
    var $level2 = $level1.find('.level-2-container');
    var $growWrapper = $level1.find('.grow-wrapper');
    var heightToSet = $growWrapper.height();

    growDiv = $level2[0];
    if (growDiv.clientHeight) {
        $level2.height(growDiv.clientHeight);
        $level2.height(0);
    } else {
        growDiv.style.height = heightToSet + "px";
    }

    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

JS-Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hps8p/

If you need all other divs to be slided in when you open one. Code can be edited to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Please do not repost large chunks of code from other answers. If the question is a duplicate then mark it as such. Otherwise please use the technique in the other answer but apply it to the code provided

Comment: Hmmm. Thought about that, but was not sure if this was exact duplicate of that. Will take care of that in future...

Comment: @vishwanath I've been playing around with what you posted.  I am having trouble though with having the 'accordion' section remain visually hidden on page load.  jsfiddle appears to have issues so here is a pen of my updated code. http://codepen.io/mdd/pen/nLpHD  You can see that it does not slide open.